# Rails - nestes resources, wrong id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Group model, which has many lists.

**Group**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_many :lists
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lists
  cattr_accessor :current_user
end
```

**List**

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  validates_presence_of :group_id
end
```

I iterate over @group.lists

```
  <% @group.lists.each do |elem| %>
<p><strong><%= elem.title %></strong></p>
<p><%= elem.body %></p>
<%= link_to 'Delete list', [elem.group, elem], method: :delete,
            data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>

  <%= link_to 'Update list', edit_group_list_path(:group_id => @group.id, :list_id => elem.id), method: :put %>

<% end %>
```

Delete method works good, but update method works wrong. Instead of creating links like http://localhost:3000/groups/9/lists/10/ where group_id is 9 and list_id is 10, it's doing something like this
http://localhost:3000/groups/9/lists/9/edit?list_id=15

Routes:

```
resources :groups do
resources :lists
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
rails routes
```

to understand where you are wrong

Anyway, the nested resource requires just `id`, so

```
edit_group_list_path(:group_id => @group.id, :id => elem.id)
```

Any other parameter is added in query string

Comment: Curses, beat me to it by 5 seconds!

Comment: Try the next time :P

Answer (score 1):

As @Ursus said, the default behavior of nested resources in rails to to accept a plain `:id` parameter for the innermost resource, `/groups/:group_id/lists/:id`.  You can also simply pass in the objects directly instead of mapping to ID integers:

```ruby
edit_group_list_path(@group, elem)
```

You can read more about nested resources here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources